# Cryptography. Write application to decrypt basic ciphers

Tags: cryptography, encryption

Evening all,

I have just began my final year at university and am studying cryptography. We have just been set the first assignment just 3 weeks in so I'm assuming it won't be a case of breaking the enigma code.

As part of the assignment there are 7 exercises with 2 further challenges consisting of various ciphers (Caesar, Vigenere, Transposition and general Substitution).
I'd like to code some sort of application to be able to decrypt these ciphers.

I don't want to cheat, im genuinely interested in the topic and feel by coding an application to decrypt the codes I'd get more out of the assignment, having to think logically about resolving each.

I'd like to think i'm reasonably competent in Java, VB and or Javascript/HTML/CSS. So any of these platforms I'm happy to try with.

If anybody can advise any pointers I'd be grateful.

Many thanks
Gary

Comment: this is international place :)

Comment: What problems are you having, specifically? I have a feeling that you aren't comfortable in any of the technologies you described, or you would have started working on deciphers already. Some of those you mentioned have trivial implementations (Caeser/Substitution). Build the ciphers first, and then try to build the deciphers. When you hit specific issues, post back here.

Comment: @gary : use assembly, more speed :-) first start with openssl command  line tool then move to any java/vb library.

Comment: Evening All, Thanks for all your comments Stefan I wasn't at the time facing any issues I was just looking to see if anybody had any advice on which route to take. We were just given a load of text already encrypted and we were challenged to decrypt them by any means possible. We are even allowed to use applications on the market to break the codes. As a beginner I felt If i push myself to build an application it will go in more than just using something somebody else has built.

Comment: I'm struggling slightly to get my head round the viginere cipher. I'm aware of the key length and have split the ciphertext into columns representing the length of the key, but am struggling to see what to do next. Frequency Analysis?? Thanks

Comment: Simon Singh (a UK-based tech journalist) made a (surprisingly good) TV series about crypto a few years ago ... and has some of the material reworked on his wesite. See http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/vigenere_cracking.html for his treatment of Vigenere.

Comment: By decrypt do you really mean to do cryptanalysis? (Are you trying to decrypt using a known key, or without knowing the key)

Comment: Thanks guys, for anybody that may use this in the future.

Comment: I managed to suss it out. Yuliy I was aware of the key length however had no idea of the key. By splitting the ciphertext into columns based on the key length, i.e. 1st, 7th, 13th letter in column 1 etc. I was then able to frequency analyse each column and identify the shift for each column which referred to the key value.

Comment: It took 3 weeks to get your first assignment? They're still treating you with kid gloves.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Simon Singh's "The Code Book"; it features Caesar, Vigenere, transposition+substitution, all the way through Enigma, Lucifer (DES) and up to asymmetric and quantum crypto, along with the ways to break some of these ciphers. The Vigenere chapter explains the cryptanalysis in great detail.